# ng-options selected not working with object as model [Angular 1.5]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

Below code and everything loads fine, except it doesn't select the default option.

Also, one of the dropdown items value for `option.groupJID` does matches with `MyCtrl.groupJID = 1655153520848838061@groups.go.to`

```
<select id="groups-list2" ng-model="MyCtrl.groupJID" 
 ng-options="option.groupJID as option.profile.name for option in MyCtrl.userGroups track by option.groupJID">
</select>
```

Please review

[image: ng-options]
[image]

Function:

```
SomeNetworkCall.then(function(success){
   MyCtrl.groupJID = success.peer; //'1655153520848838061@groups.go.to'

   MyCtrl.userGroups = success.groups;

});
```

success.groups:

```
[
      {
        "groupJID": "11110567@groups.go.to",

        "profile": {
          "name": "Flock Desktop Dev - QA issues",
          "description": "QA/Dev Channel"
        }
      },
      {
        "groupJID": "1655153520848838061@groups.go.to",

        "profile": {
          "name": "Some group name",
          "description": "awesome Channel"
        }
      }
      {
        "groupJID": "1111067890@groups.go.to",

        "profile": {
          "name": "Flock Desktop 1",
          "description": "QA/Dev Channel"
        }
      },
      {
        "groupJID": "1111045678@groups.go.to",

        "profile": {
          "name": "Flock Desktop 2",
          "description": "QA/Dev Channel"
        }
      }
]
```

Comment: have you tried passing an object in the ng-model instead if a static value ? for eg : { text : "text", value:"value" }, because ng-options gives you an object in the ng model, or check the value you are receiving in ng-model and pass that object.

Comment: @DevanshiParikh ng-model is an object `MyCtrl.groupJID` which it received over http call, same goes for `MyCtrl.userGroups`. Both are receiving data from server in 1 success function

Comment: could you add in example data for both MyCtrl.groupJID and MyCtrl.userGroups

Comment: Make sure the MyCtrl.groupJID has the same value as option.groupJID

Comment: @DevanshiParikh added JSON data

Comment: @MarcusH yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

> Be careful when using select as and track by in the same expression.

The value you specify in the *Select As* will be used as the option value but when you add a *Track By* expression the value which will be tracked is the *Select as* value and not the object.
In your case the ngModel value is `option.groupJID` and the track by expression evaluates to `option.groupJID.groupJID` which is undefined.

To make it work, you could remove the Track by expression

```
<select id="groups-list2" ng-model="MyCtrl.groupJID" 
    ng-options="option.groupJID as option.profile.name for option in MyCtrl.userGroups">
</select>
```

Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/YK1elVQkjcZ8n0x1z3Nw?p=preview)

Comment: dude you are a legend, I was working on this since last 3hrs